# How to make a circular zigzag in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon

For weeks, I have been trying to achieve how to make this.

[image: seal]

I know how to do the gradients and the fonts and everything else EXCEPT for the zigzag circle.  I only use Photoshop to design as I am really not good with Illustrator.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Like Javi I would recommend using Illustrator (even if you're not good with it, this is very simple), but would use the Star Tool.

Instead of just clicking and dragging to draw your star (which as default is 5 pointed) click the tool once on the Artboard and a menu will pop up allowing you to give the radii of the star and how many points it needs.

Then if you need the object in Photoshop you can just `copy` + `paste`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate all of your answers and I am trying all of them.

Comment: There are usually 20 different ways to do any one thing in Adobe's software. :D

Answer (score 3):

The easiest method is to simply use the **Custom Shape Tool** (Especially if you do not have or know how to use Illustrator.)

[image: Custom Shape Tool]

Then in the **Control Bar** for the Custom Shape, click the menu, and load the **Banners and Awards** shapes which ship with Photoshop and simply choose the seal image.

[image: Shapes]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Illustrator to accomplish this shape or the entire thing at that.

Open Illustrator.

1. Press <kbd>L</kbd>.
2. Select the circle shape tool.
3. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click and drag on the canvas. (Shift ensures that your shape will be symmetrical.)
4. Click Effect in the Menu and scroll to 'Distort and Transform' then 'ZigZag'.
5. A new box will open up, check the 'Preview' box and you will see the effect apply to your new circle. You can adjust the slider options and get the right effect.
6. Click OK when finished.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select your shape.
8. <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.
9. Open your photoshop document and press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

Hope this helps.

You could use the shape tool in Photoshop and select the polygon. At the top there is a section where you can select how many sides you want. To the right of it is a drop down. Select star and choose your indent. The indent is how deep each angle will be.

Answer (score 2):

In photoshop you can use the 'Polygon Tool'

Then choose the number of sides (in your case it looks to be about 56)

[image: polygon shape settings]

Click on the "gear" icon for the settings and check the "star" box and choose the amount for the points to be indented (7% seems to be working well).

[image: Select star and indent]
You can then draw the shape to the size you require.

Here is the result with the settings I've shown in the images:

[image: final result]