# How to create a wavy circle (cog like) in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I create this shape in Photoshop? It has to have the smooth lines.
See example.

I know this is easy to do in Illustrator but I do not have acess to that program.

TIA!

[image]

Comment: You can export as psd file in illustrator with transparent background and use in photoshop

Comment: I don't have access to Illustrator so I need a way to do this in PS.

Comment: this video can help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoKrjb6DAg4

Answer (score 5):

Use the **Polygon Tool**

[image]

And set the options in the Control bar across the top of the screen *before you draw*

[image]

- **Sides** (to the right of the popup options) determines how many "bumps" there are.
- **Smooth Corners** ensures the outside ridges are smooth
- **Star** means to inset the area between "Sides"
- **Inset Side By**.. should be self-explanatory, the amount of inset
- **Smooth Indents** means to round the indents as opposed to sharp angles. (you'll get more wavy, indents with this checked.. more of a point at the outer edge as opposed the "bump" look.)

With smooth indents checked....

[image]

From here it's more a matter of exploration. Because these aren't "live" shapes and you can't readily alter the options *after* the object is drawn, you will often have to guess.. draw.. delete.. refine.. draw again... and repeat until you get *exactly* what you are after.

So from the second circle above..... I'd need to reduce the number of sides and redraw to get closer to your original image.

Of course, there's also a custom shape already included with Photoshop....
[How to make a circular zigzag in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27040/how-to-make-a-circular-zigzag-in-photoshop/27048#27048)

(This is a 5 second thing in Illustrator which offers much more rapid editing of the shape and then could be copy/pasted as a path back to Photoshop and saved as a Custom Shape.)